# Order By Year with Date field Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-order-by

I am having trouble with getting my year to echo properly.

Example: I have 2 news articles one with a year of 2011 and the other 2012.  They are splitting into the correctly "year" div. But when it comes to rendering out the year, it works.  But 2011 and 2012 are stacked above each other. Something like this.

---

**2012

2011**

5.1.12 My news article

---

**Where 2011 year is suppose to go**

5.1.11 My news article

---

Here is my code.

```
<? 
$startYear = 2010;
$endYear = 2012;

for($y = $endYear; $y > $startYear -1; $y--) { ?>

<? 
$news = query("SELECT * FROM news_entries 
               WHERE title > ''
                 AND published = 1 
                 AND    date >= '" . mktime(0,0,0,0,0,$y) . "' 
                 AND date < '" .  mktime(0,0,0,0,0,$y+1) . "' 
               ORDER BY date DESC"); 
?>
```

The rest of the query.

```
         <? if($news['total']>0) { ?>
                <h3><? echo $y; ?></h3>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="first" width="125">Date</th>
                        <th>News Headline</th>
                        <th width="140">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <? do { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span><? echo date("F d, Y",$news['data']['date']); ?></span></td>
                        <td><a href="<? echo $baseURL . "news/" . $news['data']['id']  . "/" . htaccess_format($news['data']['name']); ?>" title="<? echo $news['data']['headline']; ?>"><? echo $news['data']['headline']; ?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="<? echo $baseURL . "news/" . $news['data']['id']  . "/" . htaccess_format($news['data']['name']); ?>" title="Learn More" class="button">Learn More</a></td>
                    </tr>
                     <? } while($news['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($news['object'])); ?>
                     <? }} ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="last"></td>
                        <td class="last">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" title="Back to Top" class="top">Back to Top</a></td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: I added to my original question.

Comment: Are you also putting the dates into the database as 01/01/YYYY? They never have month/day info? What you are doing above actually excludes all dates after 01/01/2012 right? (i.e. doesn't actually include 2012?)

Comment: @Kato they are doing a date range, 1 year at a time in the query.

Comment: Ah, my brain just refuses to accept that; why would you do several queries where you could do one? The data is already sorted, so why not just select the whole range at once and then iterate? Also, is there any CSS or JavaScript on this page? (factors that can contribute to your problem)

Comment: I am posting my date as text. strtotime($_POST['date']), "text"

Comment: Can you provide an example of doing it with one query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kato's comment. Typically, you get all of the results and iterate over them, printing a new header when the data changes.

Here's how this type of thing is usually handled (pseudocode):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news_enteries ORDER BY date DESC";
// Prepare statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// Bind variables
...
// Execute query
$stmt->execute() or die();

$year_header = "";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $year = date("Y", strtotime($row['date']));
   // Do we need a new year header?
   if ($year_header <> $year) {
     $year_header = $year;
     // Print year header
     echo $year_header;
   }
   // Process rest of the row
   ...
}
```